# GROUP BY AND SUM queries

Tags: php, mongodb-query

I can't find working solution for this.

I wanna for example make the query like (in SQL):

```
"SELECT SUM(visits),* FROM db_name WHERE name = 'John' GROUP BY date
```

When I use code like:

```
$data=$collection->aggregate([
   { $match: { name: "John" } },
   { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$visits" } } },
]);
```

Parser send me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']' in /usr/home
```

There is not actual documentation for queries like this in PHP.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use JSON to define the parameters to `aggregate` rather than using PHP arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use JavaScript object syntax for a PHP associative array.

PHP uses `[]` around the array and `key => value` for the elements. String constants need to be quoted.

```
$data=$collection->aggregate([
    [ $match => [ "name" => "John" ] ],
    [ $group => [ "_id" => "$cust_id", "total" => [ $sum => "$visits" ] ] ],
]);
```

Comment: Can You help me with that? (answer above)

Comment: Help you with what? I don't know MongoDB, so I can't help you with anything specific to that. I was just correcting the syntax error.